# Ubuntu 20.04 weird behaviour on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, xorg, dpkg

I had freshly dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04 a few days back.
I had installed "third-party software" during installation itself.
It worked perfectly fine for the first few times.

Then, I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove`, that, for some reason, also removed a lot of packages that had `nvidia` in the name.
I *think* I fixed this by running a `ubuntu-drivers` command, and `nvidia-smi` now successfully prints the correct details and the "Additional Drivers" app also shows that I'm using the recommended drivers (`nvidia-drivers-460`).

Yet, it's behaving very weirdly. When I load into Ubuntu, many times I get stuck on the black boot screen (where Ubuntu is written and the spiral loader is present). Sometimes it get's stuck there with the spiral loader thing frozen, sometimes it get's stuck after the loader has completed rotating.

I was somehow able to successfully boot in once (I don't know how) and was twice greeted with an error that said "`Xorg crashed with SIGBRT`, which I reported as a bug. However when I re-installed all `xorg` packages and the `ubuntu-desktop`, this error disappeared.

Yet, the black-screen boot problem still persists. For the last 2-3 boots, I was able to fix this by going into recovery mode and running `dpkg` which each time installed `libgcc1` for some reason. After doing that, it booted fine. Why's `libgcc1` getting installed each time? Why not only once?

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Try installing `libgcc1` in normal mode once and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Arka it seems to work now, thanks

Comment: Nevermind, it booted fine for the first time and then again got stuck at the boot screen